# Calculation of compression ratio using arithmetic encoding?

Tags: arithmetic, data-compression, coding-theory, encoding-scheme, entropy

Arithmetic encoding is one of the most famous entropy encoding techniques, and I am using it to encode an image.
For this, I am using the built-in function of Matlab that also gives other values such as seq, counts, and source along with the binary code.
From theory, compression is done based on the probability distribution of data. The arithmetic encoder encodes the sequence based on its probability.
Now the main thing I want to know is about the calculation of the compression ratio. Is the compression ratio only calculated using the code/binary code, or are other parts also included?
If yes, can someone please let me know how to calculate the size and other required stuff for me? These data are either present in a high precision manner or have high values.

Comment: The most obvious way to get the ratio is to compare the compressed size to the uncompressed one for the whole file.